# Is the order of FieldInfo[] Type.GetFields() Guaranteed?

Tags: c#, reflection

Currently I do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    // Declare Fields
    [FieldName("F_BAR")] public int?    Bar;
    [FieldName("F_BAZ")] public int?    Baz;
    [FieldName("BLARG")] public double? Bee;
    
    // And a custom selector
    public static string FooFields() {
        // which looks something like:
        StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder();
        foreach( FieldInfo f in typeof(Foo).GetFields() )
            fields.Append(", " +
                f.GetCustomAttributes(
                    typeof(FieldNameAttribute),
                    false)[0].FieldName );
        return fields.ToString().Substring(2);
    }
    // .. which will be used like this:
    public static string ExampleSelect() {
        return "select " + Foo.FooFields() + " from tablename";
    }
    
    // And a custom reader, formatted for the custom selector
    public static Foo Read(DbDataReader reader) {
        int i = -1;
        return new Foo {
            Bar = reader.IsDBNull(++i)
                ? (int?)null
                : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(i)),
            Baz = reader.IsDBNull(++i)
                ? (int?)null
                : Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(i)),
            Bee = reader.IsDBNull(++i)
                ? (double?)null
                : Convert.ToDouble(reader.GetValue(i))
        };
    }
}
```

Currently, it works. I realized today, that this depends on the fields being returned from `GetFields()` in the order that I declared them in the class. Is this always the expected behavior? Only in .NET?

EDIT: If there are [cases](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112174226/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/07/09/661091.aspx) when it doesn't work, can I assume it will work as long as I don't do anything to upset the cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the `GetFields` method does not return the `FieldInfo` values in any particular order.  Here is the relevant documentation snippet from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx)

> The GetFields method does not return fields in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which fields are returned, because that order varies.

Comment: Oh, hello old question. Let me accept an answer.. Looking back at it now, older, wiser.. if I still insisted on doing it this way, I would sort with LINQ on the GetFields().

Comment: This appears to be true for GetProperties() too, and therefore also for RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties() and RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeFields().

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sort the array again using FieldInfo.FieldHandle

```
        FieldInfo[] infos = GetType().GetFields();
        Array.Sort(infos, delegate(FieldInfo first, FieldInfo second)
        {
            return first.FieldHandle.Value.ToInt32().CompareTo(second.FieldHandle.Value.ToInt32());
        });
```